# WordPress admin section appears broken

Tags: wp-admin

My WordPress admin area looks like the image linked below. I have tried reinstalling WordPress using the option in the `Updates` panel. But I cannot get it to revert. Has anybody had a similar problem and knows the solution?

My guess is that it's CSS but shouldn't have to reinstall WP sorted that out?

[Need more rep to include this image in the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRmN4.png)

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your plugins? Changing themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot I can see at least 3 menu items that were added by a plugin.

Standard practice when WP breaks after an update is to:

1. Disable all plugins (You can rename the `/wp-content/plugins` directory to turn them all off at once).
2. Revert to the default (TwentyEleven) theme

Then you can re-enable your plugins one at a time to figure out which one it is that's breaking things.

Comment: I just did all the above but it didn't work. Oddly enough however the `Appearance` tab looked as expected.

Comment: Randomly tried to do that again and it worked oddly enough.

Answer (score 0):

just update `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reupload an older version of the entire public HTML and just connected it to the database. That was what worked for me.